# Computation with Floating Point Numbers: When to Round?

Tags: c, floating-point, rounding, ieee-754

I'm performing some computations in C with floating point numbers.  I'm specifically dealing with the case where I get the lowest possible single precision value for the exponent.

Say my exponent is -126 and I have to decrement it.  In this case, I can't go any lower, so I need to right shift my mantissa once.  I know I'm supposed to get the exact answer for a calculation and *then* round (to whatever place is specified).

I'm thinking of doing (let `M` be the mantissa):

```
M >>= 1;
//round mantissa
```

1. since I'm shifting the mantissa to the right and there was an implied 1 to the left of the floating point, do I need to modify M after shifting with something like:

   ```
   M |= (1 << 23)
   ```

   to ensure I have a 1 in the most significant bit?
2. It seems weird to round after losing a bit of information but is this standard / accepted practice?  Or should I calculate the full result by using more bits and *then* rounding?

Comment: "there was an implied 1 to the left "  Disagree: no implied 1 when M == -126.  [Ref](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#Exponent_encoding)

Comment: Seeing your code would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

For floating point there are "normals" and "de-normals".

For "normals" the mantissa has an implied 1 bit and the value is `( 1 + (mantissa >> mantissa_bits) ) << (exponent_value - exponent_bias)`.

For "de-normals" the mantissa does not have an implied 1 bit, the exponent is always its minimum value (or 1 less than the minimum for a normal) and the value is `(mantissa >> mantissa_bits) << (0 - exponent_bias)` or `mantissa >> (exponent_bias + mantissa_bits)`.

For de-normals, when you shift right the exponent remains the same and the mantissa is shifted instead. The least significant bits will be lost, but are used to round the mantissa (according to the rounding mode). E.g. (assuming round to nearest) `1011001b >> 5 = 10.11001b = 11b` and `1001001b >> 5 = 10.01001b = 10b`.

Note that de-normals are annoying and take special case handling that effects performance; so most modern CPUs have a special "de-normals are zero" mode (which doesn't comply with IEEE standards) where it simply replaces any de-normals with +/- 0.

If you're doing this in software it's likely to be faster to do all calculations using a larger floating point format (with better precision) and ignore de-normals (which reduces precision for tiny numbers) to end up with the same precision with a lot less headaches. If necessary, you can convert between "larger without de-normals" and "smaller with de-normals" formats. Specifically; I'd be tempted to use a 64-bit mantissa and 32-bit exponent with no de-normals, with routines to convert between this internal format to both "32-bit float" and "64-bit double".